# how to set background image using css?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to set background image .but I am background image come forward or above to current image . how to set background image  ? background image mean it always behind the current image ?

here is my code
https://codesandbox.io/s/aged-lake-wx0tf?file=/index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Static Template</title>
    <style>
      .abc::after {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0vh;
        left: 0;
        content: " ";
        background-image: url("/a.png");
        background-size: 100% 100%;
        width: 100%;
        height: 50vh;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="abc">
      <img
        src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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"
      />
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

my background image come above the glass image.

**Expected output. it should come behind the glass image**
https://codesandbox.io/s/aged-lake-wx0tf?file=/index.html:0-5825

Comment: You want the `background-image` of `.abc::after` to be "hidden" completely behind the current (glass)?

Comment: Is there a reason for using a pseudo element rather than putting the background as a background image to the actual element abc, or to the img itself?

Comment: And if I may ask, are both "images" (`::after{ background-image`} and `src`) have to be on the page at the same? Because if yes, both have to be a part of the `DOM`, meaning *elements*, and that leads to: Avoid inserting `before` and `after` to `images`.

Answer (score 0):

In css add this:

```
.abc img {
  z-index: 100
}
```

and this:

```
  .abc::after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0vh;
    left: 0;
    content: " ";
    background-image: url("/a.png");
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50vh;
    z-index: 1;
  }
```

The z-index property specifies the stack order of an element.

Also, visit: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp

Comment: Alternatively, use `.abc::before`.

Comment: @Ouroborus True.

Comment: Althugh z-index does specify the stack order of an element as you say, remember that a pseudo element has a different relationship to its element.

Comment: @AHaworth Agreed, but that doesn't make the answer less valid does it?

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Static Template</title>
    <style>
      .abc::after {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0vh;
        left: 0;
        content: " ";
        background-image: url(/a.png);
        background-size: 100% 100%;
        width: 100%;
        height: 50vh;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="abc">
      <img
        src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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"
      />
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```